# Difference on Flat mesh with subdivision modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I am creating a bookcase and I wonder why every people say that 99.9% use subdivision modifier, but is so big difference on lets say simply planks of wood? My final question is if I should use it even on melamine?

Comment: Only apply subdivision for models that have need for curvy surface. Straight planks have on need for subd modifier. I don't think every one would say 99.9% of the time you should use it. Where did you read it? I advice that you stop visiting that forum if they all say that, it's sound like a prank to me. 85% of the time you don't need a subdiv modifier, lots of stuff in the real world is straight like wall and glass panels and ... you get the point.

Comment: What do you mean with [*melamine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melamine)?

Comment: @Leander, probably this https://www.google.fr/search?q=m%C3%A9lamin%C3%A9&client=firefox-b&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9s7O9juTaAhUFZlAKHbcFDo4QsAR6BAgAEGk&biw=1827&bih=976

Comment: No i didnt read it at forum , but many big artists says it so, anyway i get your point but i also disagree with your percentage.